# TypeError: products.map is not a function - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm getting `TypeError: products.map is not a function` error when I try to loop or map through the objects currently in my state, I'm getting products from an API and putting them into my state and trying to display the objects in my state.

HomeScreen.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap'
function HomeScreen() {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
    const requestMetadata = {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method:'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/products/', requestMetadata).then(product => setProducts({product}))
    return (
        <div>
            {products.map(product => (
                <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded">
            <Card.Img src={product.image} />
            <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title as="div">
                <strong>{product.name}</strong>
            </Card.Title>
            <Card.Text as="div">
            
            </Card.Text>
            <Card.Text as="h3">
            ${product.price}
            </Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

Comment: `fetch` returns a response stream, you have to read that response stream to get the actual data. One way of doing this is by doing `fetch('').then(res => res.json()).then(data => setProducts(data))` - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json

Comment: `{product}` is the shorthand of `{product: <response from server>}`. I guess the response is an array of products. So you can try to pass it like `setProducts(product)`

Comment: ```fetch('').then(res => res.json()).then(data => setProducts(data))``` gives me ×
Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of input error

Comment: the result is the same if i change it to ```setProducts(product))```

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(product)` after fetching the data?

Comment: the output is an empty array but I have tested the API and it does give product list

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting Array list and then setting it as object of arrays. Then the problem is in your this line `fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/products/', requestMetadata).then(product => setProducts({product}))`

In details problem is with this: `setProducts({product})`

You must use Array for the [map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) use.

**update it like this:** `fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/products/', requestMetadata).then(product => setProducts(product || []))`

What changed is this only: **`setProducts(product || [])`**

Comment: @ArpitYT could you please share the response result that you get from API?

Comment: Here it is ```[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Airpods Wireless Bluetooth Headphones",
        "price": 200,
        "image": "/images/WhatsApp_Image_2020-12-03_at_12.45.48_PM.jpeg",
        "created_at": "2021-03-17"
    }
] ```

Comment: @ArpitYT if the response is really coming like above, it will work. I believe that there you are having an issue in receiving the response. The response is setting may be an `empty string` or `undefined`.

Comment: @ArpitYT, check I updated the code, it will not now throw that error if you don't get an appropriate response.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would insert the fetch function into `useEffect`.

Second, After fetching you need to take the response and parse it with `.json()` (which is also async function).

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/products/', 
    requestMetadata).then(res => res.json().then((products) => 
    setProducts(products)))
}, [])
```

Also make sure to remove the object wrapping when you use state in this way

Comment: that gives me ```',' expected.```

Comment: My bad, change the `useEffect`, forgot to add the dependency part